# Android Studio: Blank app - Gradle shows unresolved dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to make a app for Android phones. But when creating a blank project with an empty or basic activity I get these errors:

[image: error_image]

I am totally new in programming. But I am sure it's not my fault.

Comment: install those at first.

Comment: What to install? How to install?

Comment: try use com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1 instead of version 28 libraries.

Comment: Make sure you are connected to the internet when you start.

Comment: I am connected to the Internet. I download a fresh install of Android Studio, make a new app and want to debug. But still getting unresolved dependencies.